# Easiest way to generate an array of constants in Java

Tags: java, arrays, constants

I'm making an application in which I need to have a constant array of my class Note. For sake of code readability, I'd ideally generate the 108 note values for the array (octaves 0-8, 12 notes an octave) at runtime rather than having it hard-coded. This is how I'm trying to do it currently:

```
public class Note{
   ...

   public static class Constants{

        public static final int lowestOctave=0;
        public static final int highestOctave=8;
        public static final int numOfOctaves=highestOctave+1;
        public static final int numOfNotes=numOfOctaves*12;

        private static Note[]allNotesArray=new Note[numOfNotes];
        {
          for(int i=0; i<numOfNotes; i++){
             allNotesArray[i]=new Note(/*Note params*/);
          {
        }
   }
}
```

Currently, this results in an array full of nulls. I have populated arrays in the same way in final classes, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it for static classes. I know when you create a static/static final array the array itself and the array length are unchangeable, but the elements inside the array are changeable. As such, I can populate the allNotesArray in the main Note class, but this defeats the purpose of having a constants class. If anyone has any ideas on how to get it working this way that would be great, equally if anyone has any better methods on how to create the array as a constant that would be great too!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking as you do want to use constants, but don't want to use constants and fill an array with values to use it as constants, but create them dynamically at runtime. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: What are the fields that make up a Note instance?  You can create a String array with the note names (A, A# B C, etc.)  and use a double for loop for octave numbers.  You might be able to calculate the note frequencies.

Comment: I probably should have included that tbf, the Note class takes the noteName, which is an enum containing the 12 notes in western music, and the octave of the note, which is just an int. I guess I could just create a function that generates the note that would be in a certain index position whenever I need it, but this doesn't seem too effecient. Mostly interested as it would be good to know the best way to do this going forwards

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your current approach.  If you set each index to an instance of `Note`, like you do in the for loop, then you do not have an array of nulls.  You'll need to review what makes you think the array is full of nulls.  Remember that you'll have to create an instance of `Constants` to get that initializer block to run.  Or you could stick the static keyword in front of it to make it run when the class is loaded.  My guess is that you're not running the code block, and once you fix that, you won't need to do anything else because your for loop is fine.

Comment: Oh amazing, I didn't know that you could put static in front of that code block to get it to run when the static class is initialised. This solved my problem thanks - feel free to make an answer detailing this so I can award it with an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an immutable list--see https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-list for instance.

You could also write a little script to generate the source code, and then copy that in. This might actually be better than an immutable list, because then you don't have to worry about runtime errors, and you can get all the nice code completion stuff in your IDE.